# Error when sending an XML request to OpenGTS server through SOAP web services

Tags: xml, soap

I'm trying to send an XML request to OpenGTS server through web services. This is the request:

```
<GTSRequest command="version">
    <Authorization account="demo" user="admin" password=""/>
</GTSRequest>
```

When the server is running, I get the following error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GTSResponse result="error">
<Message code="RQ0031"><![CDATA[SOAP XML syntax error]]></Message>
<Comment><![CDATA[Found SOAP request:(inputXML is missing refer to the WSDL file.]]></Comment>
</GTSResponse>
```

I'm working with Windev17. I tried to send the request as both a string and an XMLDocument but the same error occured. 
Thinking that it's due to an XML syntax, I tried doubling quotes inside the string, preceding internal quotes with anti-slashes, concatenating using '+', but I get the same error.

Here is my code:

```
inputXML est une chaîne
inputXML = ...
"<GTSRequest command=""commands"">"+...
"<Authorization account=""demo"" user=""admin"" password=""/>"+...
"</GTSRequest>"
gtsServiceRequestReturn est une chaîne
gtsServiceRequestReturn = GTSServiceService.gtsServiceRequest(inputXML)
Info(gtsServiceRequestReturn)
```

Here is the contents of the WSDL file I use.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://service.war.extra.opengts.org" xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:impl="http://service.war.extra.opengts.org" xmlns:intf="http://service.war.extra.opengts.org" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <wsdl:types>
  <schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://service.war.extra.opengts.org" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <element name="inputXML" type="xsd:string"/>
   <element name="gtsServiceRequestReturn" type="xsd:string"/>
  </schema>
 </wsdl:types>
   <wsdl:message name="gtsServiceRequestResponse">
      <wsdl:part element="impl:gtsServiceRequestReturn" name="gtsServiceRequestReturn"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:message name="gtsServiceRequestRequest">
      <wsdl:part element="impl:inputXML" name="inputXML"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:portType name="GTSService">
      <wsdl:operation name="gtsServiceRequest" parameterOrder="inputXML">
         <wsdl:input message="impl:gtsServiceRequestRequest" name="gtsServiceRequestRequest"/>
         <wsdl:output message="impl:gtsServiceRequestResponse" name="gtsServiceRequestResponse"/>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:portType>
   <wsdl:binding name="GTSServiceSoapBinding" type="impl:GTSService">
      <wsdlsoap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
      <wsdl:operation name="gtsServiceRequest">
         <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
         <wsdl:input name="gtsServiceRequestRequest">
            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:input>
         <wsdl:output name="gtsServiceRequestResponse">
            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:output>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:binding>
   <wsdl:service name="GTSServiceService">
      <wsdl:port binding="impl:GTSServiceSoapBinding" name="GTSService">
         <wsdlsoap:address location="http://localhost:8080/track/Service"/>
      </wsdl:port>
   </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Can somebody help me please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting the same exception when trying to make an xml request to opengts web service..I later overcame the problem.

I think you used a saop-based tool (like saopui) to make the request. My suggestion is don't use soap-based request, just make a simple xml request. I mean remove soap headers and soap body tags.. see the below example:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.war.extra.opengts.org">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
  <GTSRequest command="version">
    <Authorization account="raju" user="admin" password="raju"/>
   </GTSRequest>      
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

like above request you may invoke your request....just remove soap headers and call like below. its working fine

```
<GTSRequest command="version">
    <Authorization account="raju" user="admin" password="raju"/>
   </GTSRequest>
```

Result:

```
<GTSResponse command="version" result="success">
 <Version>E2.4.0-B26</Version>
 </GTSResponse>
```

I am using Advanced REST client chrome extension to produce this result

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that the inputXML data structure you are passing, which is embedded within the SOAP message is probably not entity reference encoded.  If you choose not to entity reference encode the nested XML structure a second option would be to wrapped the inner XML with a CDATA section.  CDATA sections are the way to go with SOAP-UI when you have nested XML strings embedded within SOAP.